# How do I make my browsers send accept-encoding: pack200-gzip?

Tags: browser, applet, compression, gzip

I'd like to try the pack200 compression for a Java applet. I understand that the browser must support this for it to work, and according to documentation it does if it sends "Accept-encoding: pack200-gzip" to the server. However, my browsers (tried a couple) won't send that, only "Accept-encoding: gzip, deflate". Since I assumed the JRE is the key for the browser to use this new encoding, I've tried installing several Java REs from 1.6.0.34 to latest 1.7, but with no success. What am I missing here? Is there something I've misunderstood?

Googling this does not give much help unfortunally, I've tried!

Edit: OK I found out what I misunderstood. I was using a HTTP analyzer to see what the browser was sending to the server, but it's not the browser sending this particular requests of course, it's the JVM. Looking at the requests on server I see the correct accept-encoding being sent.

Comment: How it is going? Did you succeeded?

Comment: Yes thx, i just misunderstood who was sending the accept-encoding header.

Answer (score 0):

You can make [JAWS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start) support for your applet.

Both JNLP application and JNLP applet can be wrapped with [pack200](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start#Pack200_compression) and unwrapped on client machine... see [jnlp desc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/tools/pack200.html#pack200) for more details